# Slick see all items and animation to X slidesToShow

Tags: slick.js

I'm using Slick slider and I wanted create an affect like on [Tesla](https://www.tesla.com/) website:
On the page loading, see all the items (4). After a certain delay "zoom" on the initial slide and just display 3 of them.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  jQuery('.slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    swipe: true,
    cssEase: 'ease',
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    initialSlide: 2,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    centerMode: true,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
  });

  jQuery(".slider").css("opacity", 1);
}, 100);
```

Somebody knows how to do that ?

thank you

Comment: I don't believe what you're trying to do will be possible without having to completely change the underlying functionality of slick.js.